# GXT 3.0 Grid widget search

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am working with the com.sencha.gxt(3.0) grid widget. I am trying to write a Java function that searches for a string in a row(across all columns) and only display the rows that contain this string. Is there a built in, or easy method in which I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: what does this have to do with ssh? or keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

(I'm pretty sure you didn't *actually* mean to write a "yes or no" question...)

---

In short, it would be silly for GXT to assume that all data in your grid is a string or string-like or only makes sense to compare in string-y ways. Plus, you might have all your data locally so it makes sense to do a simple filter on the client, or you might really be saying 'please search all ten million rows, on the server/db, and only send back the ones that match to render on the client.

---

#### Client-side filtering

The `Store` (probably a `ListStore` for a grid, or a `TreeStore` for the tree grid, but your question doesn't specify) has a built-in method for local filtering - you give it a function that takes an item (and some other possibly-relevant data), and returns true/false indicating whether or not the item should be hidden from the user. More than one filter can be applied, and if any filter says the item is hidden, then it is gone. In other words, this can be thought of as a sql `where` clause, where all statements are joined with `and` - if you want `or`, you can implement a filter that checks if any single filter wants the item visible.

This filtering mechanism operates over the entire row item, the `T` in `Store<T>`. It doesn't know what a column is, since you could be using the store in any number of ways - items in a combobox, points on a chart, etc. It lets you build your own tools to perform the filtering. If your data is generalized in a way that makes it easy to know what all possible columns are, then you could easily write a loop over those columns that checks if any one of them contains the string, in which case return false so that the item is visible. Or, since you already built the `ColumnModel` full of `ColumnConfig`s, each of which has a `ValueProvider` and you know that it makes sense to compare each value with `.toString().contains(queryText)`, you could iterate over the columns that way.

---

#### Server-side filtering

In this case, we have very little control on the client of what is happening, since you are very likely off-loading that work to your backend database. We still know the list of columns in the column model, but we either send a query for cells matching that text, or send a single query for the entire row. Either way, we modify the paging load config object that is being used, and send a new query for the data we want, and the actual work of doing the filtering is the server's job. It sounds like from your question that this is *not* what you want, but without a lot more detail, its hard to say for sure.

Comment: Okay this is extremely helpful! I am running a ListStore, and I won't have any columns...can you explain the built-in method for local filtering? I understand you're saying to write my own function that returns true/false for whether or not an item should be in the grid...but how will the items be passed? Does the built in method iterate through the grid and pass the grid items as string values? Thank you!

Comment: A Grid without a column isn't really a grid ;) - with zero columns, it shows exactly as much data as with zero rows. Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do better. See Store.addFilter and Store.setFiltersEnabled for the actual bits of how to turn it all on and off, and update your question with what you really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through filtering.

Initially, the grid takes an argument as store and modification to the store will be directly reflected on the User Interface.

To enable filtering:

```
store.setEnableFilters(true);
```

To filter the grid, use the following commands:

```
store.addFilter(new StoreFilter<M>()
{
@Override
public boolean select(...,...,...)
{
      //return true if you want to display the row, else false
}
}
```